# Help with a proof on subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that if ($\pmb H$, *) and ($\pmb K$, *) are subgroups of ($\pmb G$, *) then ($\pmb H \cup \pmb K$, *) is a subgroup of ($\pmb G$, *) iff ($\pmb K$, *) is a subgroup of ($\pmb H$, *) (or the other way around).

Here is my attempt:

Pick any 4 elements $x_1,x_2 \in \pmb H \setminus \pmb K \neq \emptyset$ and $y_1,y_2 \in \pmb K \setminus \pmb H \neq \emptyset$ and assume
$$x_1 *y_1 =x_2$$
this means that
$$y_1=x_1^{-1} * x_2$$
but because ($\pmb H$, *) is closed we now know that
$$y_1 \in \pmb H$$
but that contradicts with
$$y_1 \in \pmb K \setminus \pmb H$$
We can see that this argument is symmetric (i.e. it gives the same result if we consider $x_1 * y_1=y_2$) so we can conclude that if $x \in \pmb H \setminus \pmb K$ and $y \in \pmb K \setminus \pmb H$ then
$$x*y \in (\pmb H \cap \pmb K)$$

This is where I get stuck. I know that I have to show that no elements can satisfy the last equation so I think that all $x*y \not \in(\pmb H \cup \pmb K)$. Like how in $(3\Bbb Z, +)$ and $(5\Bbb Z, +)$ $3 + 5 = 8 \not \in (3\Bbb Z \cup 5\Bbb Z)$.

Maybe this is a dead end but I'm not sure. I also don't want to just look up the awnser in the book.

Any hints on what I need to do?

For context: Im a freshman applied math major but because I like pure math I'm doing some self studying. I'm self studying Dan Sacrino's a first course in Abstract Algebra.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to modify the proof slightly: instead of picking $x_2$ from $H \setminus K$, consider why there would be a contradiction if $x_1 * y_1 \in H$ (or $K$).

Comment: @player3236 ahh it's the same reasoning... thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Leftarrow:$ If we have $K \le H$ or $H \le K$, then $H \cup K = H$ or $H \cup K = K$ so the left implication is clear.

$\Rightarrow:$ Now, suppose $H \cup K \le G$ but $H \nleq K$ or $K \nleq H$. Then, we have $h \in H \backslash K$ and $k \in K \backslash H$. Now, since $H \cup K \le G$ and $hk \in H \cup K$, we must have $hk \in H$ or $hk \in K$. If $hk \in H$, then $hk = h'$ for some $h' \in H$. Thus, $k = h^{-1}h' \in H$ since $H$ is a group, a contradiction. Similarly, $hk \in K$ gives a contradiction so the right implication follows.

Comment: Thanks I see what you did altough I would have much rather gotten hints instead of an corrected version of the proof.

Comment: You're welcome. Since in your solution, you got the idea of picking elements from $H \backslash K$ and $K \backslash H$, I could not find a proper hint to continue the argument. So instead, wrote the whole proof. I hope you examine the proof step by step, trying to do the rest after a step and continue to the next step if you still can't figure it out. Maybe, I should have written the proof in "spoiler" sections so that you could have seen a step and tried to figure the rest out. I apologize for that.